# How do I amend my x axis increments and y axis format on my plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, graph

I have a plot that looks like this:

[image]

My code is here:

```
df <- read_excel("Desktop/test.xlsx")
                                                                           
tidydf <- df

ggplot(tidydf, aes(Genome_size, `Trio_number`, color = Group)) +
     geom_point() +
     ylab("") +
     theme_dotplot
```

How can I:

1. make the y axis go up in increments of 1. So 1 , 2 , 3.
2. make the x axis to be in an integer form like 1991579.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your post. Please use a minimum reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `scale_y_continuous`:

```
scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,3, by = 1)
```

Use the `scales` package and `comma` function with `scale_x_continuous`:

```
library(scales)
scale_x_continuous(labels = comma)
```